# RadComboBox: click handlers lost after scrolling when using a client item template with load on demand

Tags: telerik, radcombobox

I'm using a RadComboBox in the load on demand (lazy) mode with a web service.

I'm using a client side item template of this form: `<input type='checkbox' id='cb_#= Value #'/><span>#= Text #</span>` (adding a checkbox before each item's text)

In the itemDataBound client side handler for this RadComboBox I'm retrieving the particular item's DOM element and the nested checkbox'es DOM element and adding a click handler function for each of them (using jquery's `$(element).click(function() {})`).

The click handler functions work fine until I scroll the items out of view and then scroll back, after that the click handlers are not called anymore (the checkbox selection is also lost).

I suppose this is because the DOM elements representing the items get re-created as they are scrolled in and out of view. But the itemDataBound event is raised only once and is not raised again when an item is scrolled back in view.

The only workaround I can think of is to use the onclick attribute in the HTML and reference a global function from there, but this is ugly.

Is there a nicer solution for this then using the onclick attribute?

Answer (score 0):

What it does actually it appends to `innerHtml` of the list element, but this is effectively re-moving and re-adding every node under the list element.

I worked around this by assigning my click hander and doing the databiding in the `itemsRequested` client side handler, iterating over the entire list of items obtained with the `get_items()` method of the RadCombobBox client side object.

`itemsRequested` is called every time after new items are added to the list and therefore every time after the DOM is re-created.